# SVN Merging Complication

Tags: svn, merge, branch

I've done a bit of research, and seem to find answers just about 4 inches off the mark for my situation.

We've got an SVN set up that currently has a third party continually developing on a different branching.  Periodically we need to draw in their progress.

To start, we had them sync up with our trunk to draw in out changes and resolve any potential conflicts by running:

```
svn merge url/to/trunk
```

Now, we are trying to pull back in from them.  However, svn doesn't seem to know that the last merge was from trunk.

When we run:

```
svn merge url/to/third/party/branch
```

on our trunk checkout, it's attempting to reapply the same changes, resulting in a huge number of "local add, incoming add upon merge".

Is there something I'm missing?  What would be the proper way to draw in the changes since the last merge and have SVN know about changes that started in trunk?

Also, is this the correct process we should be using to draw in changes they make as we require the updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing the `--reintegrate` flag to the merge back in to trunk

http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/2008/07/subversion-merg/ (good link on merging with reintegrate as recommended by @doc_180)

Comment: Thanks for the crazy quick response!  I thought that flag was when the branch was coming to an end of development?  Would this have any issues if development were to continue?

Comment: On my project, we frequently branch off and develop for a while, merging from trunk now and then, and we experienced similar problems to that which you mentioned when we went to merge the branch back to trunk. Now, we always use the `--reintegrate` flag when we merge a branch back to trunk, even if we are going to continue developing on the branch.

Comment: After a reintegrate, you should delete the reintegrated branch (see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchemerge.basicmerging.reintegrate). So, no, you shouldn't keep working on this branch. I don't get why you want to reintegrate from branch to trunk before the end, though, since it would make the trunk identical to the branch. Just checkout the branch and test it.

Comment: Good answer, but needs to be more ellaborate. Link on reintegrate discussion/.http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/2008/07/subversion-merg/

Comment: @JB Nizet: The branch being identical to trunk isn't necessarily a bad thing for them, since they seem to just keep the third party on the same isolated branch and pull to trunk from that branch to get that companies changes once they are completed each time.

Comment: You have two solutions then : delete the reintegrated branch and recreate it right after, or merge the reintegration commit to the branch with record only, as described here : http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.reintegratetwice

Comment: Good info @JB Nizet, though I have not experienced such conflicts, it is good to know that they exist!

Answer (score 0):

Before, I put in my 2 cents. Please let me know if you find out, how to perform merging in SVN seamlessly.

If you are performing large number of merges in SVN, then you could use the [SvnMerge.py](http://www.orcaware.com/svn/wiki/Svnmerge.py) library. This helps in automation of most of the merging use cases.

This is pasted from their FAQ?

What problem does svnmerge solve?

If we have to apply the same change to another branch, subversion already has a method for doing this.
    Traditional subversion will let you merge changes, but it doesn't "remember" what you've already merged. It also doesn't provide a convenient way to exclude a change set from being merged. svnmerge.py automates some of the work, and simplifies it. Svnmerge also creates a commit message with the log messages from all of the things it merged.

---

This tool did help me with Merging in SVN. But I eventually found Git much better than SVN, when we have to perform  frequent merges. (and hence the request to share your findings)

Comment: pls look in to the usage example section.